# How does Docker implement a DNS nameserver?

Tags: docker, networking, dns

I'm trying to piece together how Docker manages DNS and networking between its containers.

I have the following containers running on the same Docker network. I'm on Mac OS so they're running on a Linux VM (via `docker-machine`).

I've also included the IP of the `nameserver` used for DNS, as defined in the local `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
+------------+   +------------+   +------------+
|   rails    |   |  postgres  |   |   redis    |
|            |   |            |   |            |
| 127.0.0.11 |   | 127.0.0.11 |   | 127.0.0.11 |
+------------+   +------------+   +------------+
                       |
                       ↓
+----------------------------------------------+
|          Linux VM (docker-machine)           |
|             nameserver 10.0.2.3              |
+----------------------------------------------+
                       |
                       ↓
+----------------------------------------------+
|                     OSX                      |
|           nameserver 192.168.203.3           |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

My understanding is that Docker defines `/etc/resolv.conf` with a `nameserver` to use for DNS resolution. It also runs this `nameserver` and will return an address based on a container name (if found). So my `rails` container sees the other two containers with hostnames `postgres` and `redis`.

1. Where is this DNS server running? Can I see this process running somewhere? Does it run on the `docker-machine` as another containerized process I can't see?
2. How does Docker implement this DNS server? Does it use `bind`? Or another library?
3. If the DNS server is running on the `docker-machine` (`10.0.2.3`), how does it expose itself as `127.x.x.x` to each individual container?

Any other insight into how this works would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the [core](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/pull/841). You can't see it as an OS process.

Also, there's [a good explanation](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/bbd9469e7a57a713b81faa44207dc5daffc728fa) how it works with different network configurations